# jQueryUi 1.11 stacking modal dialogs in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm having a problem with stacking 2 modal dialogs in Firefox (no problems in Chrome).

When the second modal Dialog is opened through a button on the first dialog, it does not "disable" the first one, I can still click on the first modal dialog and if I do, the second dialog is coverd by the first one.

The thing is that if I click on the button, which opens the second modal dialog, twice, close the Dialog and re-open it through a button-click it works as intended (i.e. I can access the second modal dialog but not the first one).

I think these are all the relevant Code-Parts:

html:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script src = "js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/wizard.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../css/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/spectrum.css">
    <script src = "js/spectrum.js"></script>
    <script src = "../java.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/wizard.js"></script>

<body>


 <div id="PopUpTip" class="dialog ui-dialog-content ui-front"   style="position:relative; height:auto; width: 1280px;">
 </div>

    <div id="dialog_wizard" class="dialog ui-dialog-content ui-front" style="position:relative;">
        <div class = "quicktip">
            ?<span hidden>blabla</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#dialog_wizard').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: '840',
        height: 'auto',
        title: 'Wizard',

        open: function (event, ui) {
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-icon').css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
            jQuery('#dialog_wizard').dialog('widget').position({
                my: "top",
                at: "top",
                of: window
            });
        },
        close: function () {
            //abbrechen();
        }
    });



    jQuery('#dialog_wizard').dialog('open');


    jQuery('#PopUpTip').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "QuickTip",
        width: '720',
        resizable: false,
        stack: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-icon').css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
            jQuery(this).dialog('widget').position({
                my: 'center',
                at: 'center',
                of: jQuery('#dialog_wizard')
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery('#PopUpTip').bind("dialogclose", function (event, ui) {
        //jQuery('#theContent').html();
    });

    function setContent(text)
    {
        jQuery('#theContent').html(text);
        jQuery('#PopUpTip').dialog("option");
        jQuery('#PopUpTip').dialog("open");
        jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function()
        {
            jQuery('#PopUpTip').dialog('close');
        });
    };

    jQuery(document).on("click",".quicktip",function()
    {
        setContent(jQuery(this).children(':first-child').text());
    });
}
```

Comment: When you mean `access`, what exactly do you mean? like move it around? highlight text? if so, just add `jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay:eq(2)').css('zIndex', 101);` to the `open:` function of your `jQuery('#PopUpTip').dialog({` and that should resolve it. [Something like this should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ukts6s/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes that's what I meant by access, unfortunately your solution does not solve my problem, in FireFox.
Using Firebug I was able to find out that the z-Index of the second dialogs "ui-widget-overlay" is 999 when I click the button for the first time and when I do the 'double click, close, re-open'-thing I described, the z-Index is 1001 and "in front of" the first modal Dialog... If this is of any use

Comment: Okay, you got me on the right track.  
I added what you suggested to `open:` though it's:  
`jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay:eq(1)').css('zIndex', 1001);` since `eq()` is zero based.
And I added:  
`jQuery('.ui-dialog:eq(1)').css('zIndex', 1001);` 
to increase the dialogs z-index accordingly